# Mostrar todas las imagenes de un directorio en mi pagina web

Tags: php, html, jquery, .net

tengo una solución en .Net la cual tiene una pagina que muestra mis imágenes, quisiera que en ella se muestren todas las imágenes de un directorio (carpeta), ya que son muchísimas no quisiera pasarme toda una vida referenciando con un img src="" a cada una de ellas quisiera hacerlo todo de una sola, ademas considerar la que los archivos seguirán agregándose. He leído foros con códigos que hacen en PHP pero no se como adaptarlo, normalmente lo hago así:

```html
<img src="http://www.deceroadoce.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/leopardo-museo-prehistoria-valencia.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="border-radius:10px;" width:300%; height:200%; />
  <img src=" http://jsequeiros.com/sites/default/files/imagen-cachorro-comprimir.jpg" class="img-responsive" style="border-radius:10px;" width:300%; height:200%; />
```

pero lo que quisiera es no usar el src para cada imagen ya que como menciono son muchas y con la posibilidad que sigan aumentando, dejo el codigo PHP que encontre pero que aun no lo implemento, gracias

```html
<?php
echo "<h3>Index</h3>\n";
echo "<table>\n";
$directorio = opendir(".");
while ($archivo = readdir($directorio))
   {
   $nombreArch = ucwords($archivo);
   $nombreArch = str_replace("..", "Atras", $nombreArch);
   echo "<tr>\n<td>\n<a href='$archivo'>\n";
   echo "<img src='./imagenes/carpeta.png' alt='Ver $nombreArch'";
   echo " border=0>\n";
   echo "<b>&nbsp;$nombreArch</b></a></td>\n";
   echo "\n</tr>\n";
   }
closedir($directorio); 
echo "</table>\n";
?>
```

Comment: Quieres resolver el problema en php o .Net?

Comment: emm...bueno en realidad el proyecto lo tengo en .net en un aspx pero mencionaba lo de php porque la info que busco siempre sale la solución relacionada en php, gracias =)

Comment: estas utilizando MVC. net?

Comment: no, solo un nuevo sitio web, sin clases ni nada, solo mascara en html + css + js y masterpage.

Comment: ahora si me confundi...:( que tipo de plantilla estas utilizando de Visual Studio al generar el proyecto?

Comment: jejeje, ok te dejo el enlace de mi solución en una imagen: https://ibb.co/mr0Ric

Comment: Importante lo que estas utilizando es un proyecto de tipo website en aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza la siguiente solución, tomando en consideracion los archivos que te listo a continuación:

**MasterPage.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" Inherits="_Default" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="head">
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1">
 </asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image nuevaImagen;
        ContentPlaceHolder contenido = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

        string[] imagenes = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("/img/"));
        foreach (var img in imagenes)
        {
            nuevaImagen = new Image();
            nuevaImagen.ImageUrl = "/img/" + Path.GetFileName(img);
            contenido.Controls.Add(nuevaImagen);
        }
    }
}
```

> Es bueno recalcar que tienes un proyecto de tipo Website en ASPX.

Comment: Excelente! funciona, pero una consulta, siempre va tener que ser cargado en el ContentPlaceHolder1? ya que qusiiera darle estilo al default y considerar que tengo otras paginas ya estructuradas, igual gracias!

Comment: Puedes cargarlo donde quieras depende de ti. Si necesitas cargarlo en otro lugar solo modifica esta linea ContentPlaceHolder contenido = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("tuContenedor");

Comment: gracias, cierro la consulta (Y).